# Looking for guidance on VB Code for Excel that will create action between two dynamic tables in each sheet.

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that allows me to keep track of a customer with general details (name, phone number, address...) bu then also keep a very specific list of all the products they have ordered. I want to be able to run reports on frequency of all details including what has been ordered. I have a bit of programming experience but not a whole lot of Excel experience so I know how I would write a program but not exactly how to do it in Excel. My thought is to have one sheet dedicated to the general specifications of the customer and then a second sheet that keeps track of the orders per customer. I want to be able to click on a hyperlink or something of the sort that will take me to the second sheet and automatically fill in the customer name. I want the first sheet to have the guest information running horizontally in rows but then the second sheet would have the names running horizontally on the top row and the orders would go down each column under the names. This way it keeps all of my sheets tidy and allows for me to run the type of reports I'm looking for. The main issue I'm having is figuring out a way to create a link that will do the action I want. I understand how to program but don't know Visual Basic very well but if someone was able to offer a similar code I would be able to decipher it and change it to my needs. Or if someone has a more efficient thought on how to set up the spreadsheet I'm all ears! Thanks a ton!

Comment: For the moment you dont have to think about any programming. Just decide how to organize your data and use Excel's formulas and `Hyperlinks`. Yes Excel permits you to insert hyperlinks to navigate between worksheets and ranges. You should think of VBA when you have specific problems that Excel's built-in features dont provide.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I have tried to use the hyperlink but they I can only decide what cell it goes to. I can manually change the cell when writing the hyperlink but I'm looking for a dynamic solution. Maybe there is a better way for me to set up my spreadsheet.

Comment: Post a sample of the data and your desired output. Maybe we can help then.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to create a pivot table with a data model.
The instructions are longer then what it actually takes!
here are few tutorials about the subject:

[youTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_SRHts2g7o)

[MSDN instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-Power-Pivot-in-Microsoft-Excel-fdfcf944-7876-424a-8437-1a6c1043a80b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

PS don't write code in Excel unless strictly necessary. If it's a data issue, use data model

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll check them out. I'm used to figuring out solutions by writing code so that's kinda what I jumped to but hopefully this is what I need.

Comment: Ok I've reviewed the material but I'm having an issue setting up the spreadsheet to be viable for a pivot table. The table needs to be two dimensional but since what the customer purchased is variable I'm not sure how to set the table up. I haves say six categories of purchasable items but many options in each category so each customer information line will be different. This is whats been giving me issues all along.

Comment: Now it's the tough part: how to create relationship between the tables? Post the data in the tables, maybe we can advise you (modify the question)